# Safari - download .CSV file instead of open it

Tags: javascript, csv, safari

Are there any solutions for downloading a .CSV file that generated on server instead of opening it on Safari ?
My system:

> MAC OS X El Capitan 10.11.5
>   Safari 9.1.1

I used this method to download an .ICS file and it works  `document.location = <link to file>;`. However when I applied it for downloading .CSV file, it just open the file on browser.

I also tried to use `download` attribute with the instructions from somewhere in stackoverflow but it still doesn't work

```
var link = $("<a />");
link.appendTo("body");
link.attr("id", "csvDwnLink");
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var csv = "\ufeff" + "col1;col2;col3",
    blob = new window.Blob([csv], {type: 'text/csv, charset=UTF-8'}),
    csvUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob),
    filename = 'export.csv';

link.attr({'download': filename, 'href': csvUrl, 'target': '_blank'});
$(link)[0].click();
```

the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/628mmkww/2/

Is anyone facing the same problem with me ?
Thanks.

Comment: "somewhere in stack overflow" nice

Comment: excuse me, I meat I got the instructions from another answer in this site but I cannot remember where is it, I just keep the link to jsfiddle.

Comment: The `download` attribute is not supported in production versions of Safari.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=download